# Can Meraki security appliances interoperate with openvpn?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, openssl

I know this is a long shot, but has Meraki said anything about interoperating with SSL vpns such as openvpn?

Comment: Ok, please educate me on how to improve.  Down votes without any reason aren't as helpful as ones that have them.

Comment: I think this was a perfectly reasonable question (I found this thread because I was wondering the same). Maybe the downvotes came from security elitists (the types who would tell people to "RTFM" rather than at least giving a pointer where to find more information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just going to quote from [the docs](https://docs.meraki.com/display/MX/Connecting+to+a+third-party+VPN+device) here:

> Currently, MX series support for third-party VPN interoperability requires the following:
>
> - Preshared keys (no certificates)
> - LAN static routes (no routing protocol for the VPN interface)
> - Phase 1 (IKE Policy): 3DES, SHA1, DH group 2, lifetime 8 hours
> - Phase 2 (IPsec Rule): Any of 3DES, DES, or AES; either MD5 or SHA1; PFS disabled; lifetime 8 hours

So, no, no OpenVPN support. If you need OpenVPN support, I suggest you contact your Meraki rep.

Comment: I'll give this the answer, but I was hoping (and still am hoping) that someone had heard about their plans.  I wasn't clear about wanting plans rather than current features.  Juniper has an SSL VPN appliance and I was hoping they would ante up to compete.